# What is the new link between EPTimeCardDetail and EPEmployee?

Tags: acumatica

I have an older customization that uses BQL to join EPTimeCardDetail to EPEmployee - and it was linked by EPTimeCardDetail's ownerID to EPEmployee's UserID.   Acumatica has seen fit to change the EPTimeCardDetail.ownerID from a GUID to an int - and now there is no way to link those two.

I can't find anything that would use EPTimeCardDetail's ownerID (which is now an int) - I tried BAccount's bAccountID - but that isn't it.

Can anyone tell me the new link between EPTimeCardDetail's ownerID and something in EPEmployee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new OwnerID corresponds to the ContactID.
So you can join EPTimeCardDetail.OwnerID to EPEmployee.DefContactID

Comment: Beauty.  Thanks much, Dmitrii.. ;D